# SSO: wiring a launch of an external app to a button

Tags: single-sign-on, connected-apps, identity-provider

I am using Salesforce as IdP using SAML 2.0. Currently this connected app can be opened through app launcher for single sign on to third party application.

However it is also desired to open this connected app using button/custom button on detail/lightning page to directly open the third party application. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

On the Connected App details page grab the value of `IdP-Initiated Login URL` in *SAML Login Information* section and use that URL in your button.

Comment: Thanks @identigral!